# Creating an availability ring using google maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am pretty new to the Google Maps API so looking for some advice. I am trying to make a dashboard which allows companies to set their availability zone using google maps and a radius around their location so say 5 miles.

I then want to be able to run a postcode lookup and return any companies who 'serve' the area covering that postcode.

So far I have reached a point where a company can drop a pin onto the map and place a radius around themselves but I have no idea where to go from there! I can pull the Longitude and Latitude of that radius but I'm not sure how I would handle the data from there really.

Like I say I am new to the Maps API so be nice and excuse my naivety sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to do more than simple radius options, you'll need to look into representing Polygons in Google Maps.  Since zip codes are often delineated by odd boundaries, it would be a requirement. If you obtain and store them in GeoJSON, it's usually pretty easy to work through loading them in as a JSON object.

The basics of a Polygon are:

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: pointList
});
```

In this case, `pointList` is your series of points that form the Polygon.  After that, you can perform customization, add on click events, etc., but this is the bare minimum you need to load a polygon (assuming you already have a map object).

You can manually add points for very small testing purposes, but the GeoJSON route will lend better to development with a larger number of polygons.

You can find an example of loading GeoJSON polygons (a multipolygon in this case) into maps here:

http://www.alecbennett.com/projects/loadgeojson/

For zip code cartographic information, some is available here:

http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html

And if you want someone that has already done some of the heavy lifting, check here:

https://github.com/ssoper/zip-code-boundaries

Comment: Thanks for the response and the detail you put in! I don't doubt the information you have provided will be helpful :) I would vote you up but I am new to SO and have no rep! :(